# URLs rewrite using regex pattern

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite URL's using .htaccess to redirect all users from old sitemap to the new URL's. The old URLs looks like this:

```
http://server.linux.example.com/a/v/c/document_title1.php
http://server.linux.example.com/jp/x/1/o/document_title32.php
http://server.linux.example.com/kr/a/a/2/document_title12343.php
http://server.linux.example.com/cn/6/z/z/document_title124.php
```

I need to keep first directory and then remove all sub-directories, including slashes and characters (letters and numbers between /) so the new URLs will look like this:

```
http://server.linux.example.com/document_title1.php
http://server.linux.example.com/jp/document_title32.php
http://server.linux.example.com/kr/document_title12343.php
http://server.linux.example.com/cn/document_title124.php
```

This is what I made so far using help from stackoverflow.com.

```
(?<=http://server\.linux\.example\.com/)(jp/|kr/|cn/)?.*(?=\.php)
```

regex101.com shows that this is a valid regex but I'm having problems with implementing this within the .htaccess as I'm reciving 500 erros.

```
ReWriteRule (?<=http://server\.linux\.example\.com/)(jp/|kr/|cn/)?.*(?=\.php)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?(jp/|kr/|cn/)?.+/([^/]+\.php)$ /$1$2 [L]
```

You can redirect (and not only rewrite) with `[R=302]` instead of `[L]`.

And to find a problem, look at your error logs.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?(jp/|kr/|cn/)?.+/([^/]+\.php)$ /$1$2 [R=302]` did the trick on Apache/2.4.25 (Debian). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd chose an approach like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/.+/([^/]+\.php)$ /$1/$2 [END]
```

You may need to add some exceptions depending on your specific situation, but in general it should do what you want.

That rule should work likewise in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") and in the real http servers host configurations.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I just tested your solution and unfortunately it gives me 500 error :(

Comment: Hm, then you need to check your http servers error log file to find out what the actual issue is.

Comment: A wild shot, but might be the issue here: maybe you operate a very old, outdated version of the apache http server which does not yet know the `[END]` flag. Have a try replacing it by the `[L]` flag.

Comment: I rechecked, just to be certain since I did not actually test the rule before I posted it. But the check is fine, the rule is valid and working as expected.

Comment: And with `^` ?:  `RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/.+/([^/]+\.php)$ /$1/$2 [L]`

Comment: @arkascha I'm running Apache/2.2.22 (Debian). My error.log displays "RewriteRule: unknown flag 'END'". As per Croises sugesstion I have replaced [END] with [L]. The 500 error is fixed but the url rewriting is not working. Due to the custom setup I'm unable to upgrade to Apache 2.4. Any workarounds for this? Thanks

Comment: @Croises I have tested it, the error 500 is gone but the redirect is not working.Thanks

Comment: Guys, I have tested both directives on Apache/2.4.25 "RewriteRule /?([^/]+)/.+/([^/]+\.php)$ /$1/$2 [END]" and "RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/.+/([^/]+\.php)$ /$1/$2 [L]" and when I'm accessing http://server.linux.example.com/kr/a/a/2/document_title12343.php I'm not being redirected to http://server.linux.example.com/kr/document_title12343.php - seems like nothing happened :(

Comment: @Croises Sure, you are right, I missed that. Corrected the answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith Actually it was me in a comment above mentioning the `[L]` flag. Fine it fixed the internal server error (http 500). But the older version of the apache http server does not explain why the rule does not get applied.

Comment: I fail to understand why the rule does not get applied. I suggest you add your current `.htaccess` file as an update to the question. And also tell us _where_ that file is located.

Comment: [R=302] solved the problem. Thanks for helping to solve this problem.